# The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path is not rooted

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

we are moving our web application which is running in 32 bit server as  website and also in the 64 bit server.

while uploading text file into server i got the error like :

> "The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path `http:\\mypath\CitiDirect\TimeSheet2.txt` is not rooted. 
>   "

but its working fine 32 bit server as in web application.
the file upload code is :

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("\\" & Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR") _
                        & "\CitiDirect$\TimeSheet2.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this workaround:

upload your file in a temporary folder then using

```
Fileupload1.SaveAs("\\" & yourtmppath)
file.move(source,destination)
```

then use this coz if the source is in use it will be copied but not deleted from original      directory

```
if file.exist(source) then file.delete(source)
```